# Jquery FadeIn / FadeOut Delay

Tags: jquery, html

Im using JQuery to fade out and fade in a new image into my web page. The problem is it seems as though the next lines of code in my program are being run before the FadeOut function has finished running. Is there a way of adding a delay after the FadeOut function so that the next line of code will not be ran until the fade has finished?

I should have probably added my code. See below:-

```
var main = function(){
    $('.container-photos img').on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).css({
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'border-color': 'red'
            });
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $(this).css({
                'cursor': 'default',
                'border-color': 'grey'               
            });
        },
        click: function() {
            var imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');


            var lastSeven = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.length - 7); 

            var newUrl = "images/photos/large/image_00" + lastSeven;    

            switch(newUrl) {
                case "images/photos/large/image_00001.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00002.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00003.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00004.jpg":
                    divWidth = 375;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00005.jpg":
                    divWidth = 213;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00006.jpg":
                    divWidth = 157;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00007.jpg":
                    divWidth = 147;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00008.jpg":
                    divWidth = 364;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00009.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00010.jpg":
                    divWidth = 171;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00011.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00012.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00013.jpg":
                    divWidth = 368;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00014.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00015.jpg":
                    divWidth = 375;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00016.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00017.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00018.jpg":
                    divWidth = 375;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00019.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00020.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00021.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00022.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00023.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00024.jpg":
                    divWidth = 166;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00025.jpg":
                    divWidth = 142;
                    break;
                case "images/photos/large/image_00026.jpg":
                    divWidth = 143;
                    break;      
                default:
            }      

            $('.main-image').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $(this).attr('src',imageUrl);
            });




            $('.main-image').css('margin-left','-' + divWidth+'px');    




            $('.main-image').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(this).attr('src',newUrl);
            }); 




        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: can you please share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do the following:

```
function() {
 $(element).fadeOut(300);
 $(element2).delay(300).fadeIn(300);
}
```

or ***(this being the better option, called a callback)***

```
$(element).fadeOut(300, function() {
 $(element2).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how it works:

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#element').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
      $('#element').delay(1200).fadeIn(2200);
});

$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#element').delay(1000).fadeOut(2200);
          $('#element').delay(1200).fadeOut(2200);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) jQuery's function as such:

```
$(el).fadeOut(500).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
```

You can directly use a callback function in the [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function also:

```
$(el).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

You can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(el).animate({
    'opacity': 0
}, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 'linear');
});
```

But please note that `.fadeOut()` function will set the CSS `display` property to `none` after having animated the CSS `opacity` property to `0`*. This `animate()` function only trick with the opacity.

> <sup>*The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing the asynchronous soul of JavaScript trying to write synchronous code.

If you are writing something like

```
$( '.domclass' ).fadeOut( 250, 'easeOutQuad' );
doSomething();
$( '.domclass' ).fadeIn( 500, 'easeInQuad' );
```

this will definetely NOT work as you might expect because of the asynchronous approach of JavaScript.

You should probably consider using callbacks

```
$( '.domclass' ).fadeOut( 250, 'easeOutQuad', function( e ) {

    // This code will be executed when the fadeOut ends
    doSomething();

    $( '.domclass' ).fadeIn( 500, 'easeInQuad', function( e ) {

        // This code will be executed when the fadeIn ends
        doSomethingElse();

    } );

} );
```

Applying the asynchronous approach to your code this is what you get (If I understand what you want to achieve):

```
        /* START of code excerpt */

        $('.main-image').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).attr('src',imageUrl);

            $(this).css('margin-left','-' + divWidth+'px');    

            $(this).fadeIn(1000, function() {

                $(this).attr('src',newUrl);

            }); 

        });

        /* END of code excerpt */
```